# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, импорт

settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "data_access",
    "api.vehicles.apps.VehiclesApiConfig",
]
```

api.vehicles.apps

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete

from api.vehicles.signals import vehicle_save_signal_receiver, vehicle_deleted_signal_receiver
from data_access.models.vehicle import Vehicle


class VehiclesApiConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "api.vehicles"

    def ready(self):
        post_save.connect(receiver=vehicle_save_signal_receiver, sender=Vehicle)
        post_delete.connect(receiver=vehicle_deleted_signal_receiver, sender=Vehicle)
```

api.vehicles.signals

```
def vehicle_save_signal_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
    print("vehicle_save_signal_receiver")


def vehicle_deleted_signal_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
    print("vehicle_deleted_signal_receiver")
```

ошибка  `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.` на импорте Vehicle в api.vehicles.apps, но data_access в INSTALLED_APPS перед api.vehicles

почему такое может быть ?

Comment: попробуйте сделать этот `from data_access.models.vehicle import Vehicle` импорт локальным в  методе ready

Comment: @MikhailLazko в целом норма вариант. Если хотите, давайте оформим как ответ с:

Comment: спасибо, не обязательно, рад что помог, у джанги есть такая проблема если обращаешься к любой модели до того как все приложения будут инициализированы то она ругается, не помню только какие причины у этого архитектурные

Comment: позволю себе маленький вопрос коментарий, а почему было принято решение разделить слой приложения апи и модель данных по разным аппам? вроде это не очень согласуется со стандартной идеологией приложений в джанго, да и слой контролирующий транзакции и авторизацию нужно будет переиспользовать если кому другому нужен будет доступ к бизнес модели. И регистрация сигналов происходит в апи, то есть модель данных без этих хендлеров будет работать успешно?

Answer (score 1):

Поборол эту ошибку, добавив перед импортом моделей

```
from django import setup
django.setup()
```